# Increase corner radius of Mac menu bar app window

Tags: swift, swiftui

Was wondering how I can increase the corner radius for a Mac menu bar app. For example, on the Mac, clicking on the battery icon vs control center gives windows with different corner radiuses. I'm using SwiftUI's MacMenuBarExtra by the way. [image: control center] [image: battery]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use a clear window and draw the background manually.

Comment: @jnpdx how would you access the underlying window in a purely SwiftUI app?

Comment: Definitely more complicated than if you manage it outside of the SwiftUI lifecycle. You can embed an `NSViewRepresentable` and then get the `window` property of that `NSView`